# Use chatter:userPhotoUpload without losing query parameters

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying out the `<chatter:userPhotoUpload>` Visualforce component on a page, and have run into a funny issue.  After a user uploads their photo, the page is refreshed -- *but without any query parameters* -- which causes errors if your page requires any parameters to work properly.

Here's a contrived example.  Create a new page called `TestPage` with this content, then load it with a valid Case id and upload a chatter photo.  When the page reloads, the case id has been lost.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <chatter:userPhotoUpload />
    {!Case.Subject}
</apex:page>
```

I'm also filing this as a bug with SFDC, but wanted to ask here in case there are any known work-arounds for this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take II: The fix will be available in the Spring '14 release (Feb 2014) --- many thanks @Benj for the heads-up.

Comment: Does implicitly state that it is a bug and is not intended to behave this way. May not provide a work around, but still worth an answer imo. Voting can take care of the rest.

Comment: @iningram, I logged this as ticket #09480429, but it was summarily closed by support as a "developer request" since I don't have Premier Support.

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed in the Spring '14 release (Feb 2014)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? e.g. how do you know this?